# How do I setup an endpoint for amp-consent?

Tags: amp-html

I have no idea what code I need to place in the document referenced by the URL for checkConsentHref.

I've used the example code from https://amp.dev/documentation/examples/user-consent/basic_user_consent_flow/?format=websites.

I know the checkConsentHref should be my own url, but what document needs to go in that location and what code should go in it?

```
<amp-consent layout="nodisplay" id="consent-element">
<script type="application/json">
{
  "consents": {
    "my-consent": {
      "checkConsentHref": "https://example.com/api/show-consent",
      "promptUI": "consent-ui"
    }
  }
}
</script>
</amp-consent>
```

I expect there to be some function at checkConsentHref location to take some kind of action.

Comment: Same problem here. It would be so great if I wouldn't have to setup an own endpoint just for this... why is that not possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a good explanation here: [About consent](https://azei-package-test.com/abe/user_consent/basic_user_consent_flow/index.html)

A CORS endpoint can be specified via the `checkConsentHref` attribute. The `amp-consent component` will check via a POST request if the consent UI needs to be shown. The response to this request should look like this:

```
{
  "promptIfUnknown": true
}

#or

{
  "promptIfUnknown": false
}
```

So you can add there e.g `https://ampbyexample.com/samples_templates/consent/getConsent` 
First time I saw this url, I thought that it is only exapmle, but it works.
This url store information about showing the consent. You can check it in your `JS` console.

`https://ampbyexample.com/samples_templates/consent/getConsent` will returns `"promptIfUnknown": true` or `"promptIfUnknown": false` based on previous user action

I do not know If it is a good practice to use this "example" url instead own.

Comment: But I need to spin up a cloud function or a REST endpoint just for this?

Comment: Looks like https://amp.dev/documentation/examples/api/get-consent/ endpoint also replies to REST POST requests (but not regular HTTP requests)